# Prime factorization word problem

Tags: number-theory

> John is throwing a party for at least $4$ other friends and buys a bag of $546$ pieces of candy. At the party, they evenly distribute the candies among all people. If the number of people present is odd, what is the smallest number of people that could be present?

This question was asked on a elementary number theory course regarding prime factorization. In that context finding the prime factors of $546$ results in $546  = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$. How does this information help with the problem? I'm tempted to say that the result would be $7$, since it's the first prime factor $> 4$, but I'm not quite sure if that's the case here. Any clearance here would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct: you need the smallest odd divisor of $546$ that is greater than $4$, and that is $7$. If the number of people were not known to be odd, the answer would be $6$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $546$ candies to be distributed evenly, so the number of people present should be a factor of $546$. The smallest odd factor greater than $4$ is $7$, the answer.